# How to hover over an image and show an information box in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to hover over an image and while hovering over the image an information box pops up giving details about that picture. How do you do this in angular?

Comment: You can simply use title in the html tag like, <p title="World Health Organization">WHO </p>

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic CSS for this

```
<div id="parent">
    Some content
    <div id="hover-content">
        Only show this when hovering parent
    </div>
</div>


#hover-content {
    display:none;
}

#parent:hover #hover-content {
    display:block;
}
```